# MemcachedClient cas operation not returning already Exists

Tags: java, memcached

I have the following unit test which uses the net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient

```
    @Test
public void testCASFailsWrite() throws Exception {
    Integer begin = new Integer(3);
    client.set(key, 0, begin);

    CASValue<Object> casValue = client.gets(key);

    Assert.assertNotNull(casValue);
    Assert.assertTrue(casValue.getValue() instanceof Integer);

    Integer fromCache = (Integer) casValue.getValue();  
    Integer nextSeq = new Integer(fromCache + 9);

    long myInvalidValue = casValue.getCas() - 1;

    CASResponse response = client.cas(key, myInvalidValue, nextSeq);
    Assert.assertEquals(CASResponse.EXISTS, response);
}
```

I expect the CASResponse to show the value already exists since I have an invalid casValue, however it comes back as OK on the last Assert.  I want to make sure my key handles being concurrently updated across multiple JVMs.  My unit test is using an embedded memcache process via an implementation of com.thimbleware.jmemcached.AbstractCache.  Can I rely on the CASResponse to show EXISTS when my key is already in memcache and I don't have the same casValue()?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you are running this test against a brand new instance of memcached. The cas value is global in a memcached instance and the first set receives cas value 1, the second set gets cas value 2, and so on. When you run the test your key gets a cas value of 1. Since your invalid cas is generated by just decrementing the cas value of this key your invalid cas value ends up being 0. Specifying a cas value of 0 in an update means ignore the cas and just update. set myInvalidValue to some random number like 123456 and this problem will go away. Another interesting thing is that if you where to run your test above twice it would pass the second time.

Comment: I updated my code and set myInvalidValue = 459 and it still responded Ok.  Interestingly enough I see the casValue being updated.  It appears com.thimbleware.jmemcached.AbstractCache doesn't enable cas support.  I pointed this unit test to an external memcached server and it works as expected.